# How to store values found within loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network, tensor

I am trying to run multiple nested loops and then retrieve an array of values based on a condition within the loop. I have 14 alpha values I need to test, and each on needs to be tested for an epoch of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. As I test each alpha value for all 6 epochs I want to record the number of times the error is less then 0.05. At the end I want a 2D array where the rows represent the 14 different alpha values and each column is a different epoch value.

I want to know if there is a better way of doing this then using a tensor with numpy. Using this method gives me a lot of issues when I try to scale this project.

For people who are interested this is just a 2 input, single hidden layer, output neural network to teach myself about back propagation. The code i submitted is for 2 neurons but I am trying to scale this to 4 right now and eventually n neurons. And storing the error values and calculating the success to output in a 2D array where I could see what alpha and epoch pair produce the best results would be very helpful.

I have already completed this task before using this code:

```py
import numpy as np
for l in range(0,14):
    alpha = [0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
    nEpoch=1
    for n in range(0,6):
        nSuccess = 0
        w11f = np.zeros(nEpoch*nTrain)
        w12f = np.zeros(nEpoch*nTrain)
        for j in range(0,50):
            w11 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w12 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w21 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w22 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w31 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w32 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w41 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            w42 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            b4 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            b3 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            b2 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            b1 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            ww1 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            ww2 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            ww3 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            ww4 = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            bb = 0.5 - np.random.rand();
            
            sp = random.sample(a,nTrain + nTest)
            p = 0
            for epoch in range(0,nEpoch):
                for i in range(0,nTrain):
                    y1 = b1 + w11*x[sp[i],0] + w12*x[sp[i],1]
                    y2 = b2 + w21*x[sp[i],0] + w22*x[sp[i],1]
                    y3 = b3 + w31*x[sp[i],0] + w32*x[sp[i],1]
                    y4 = b4 + w41*x[sp[i],0] + w42*x[sp[i],1]
                    
                    dxx1 = y1 > 0
                    xx1 = y1*dxx1
                    
                    dxx2 = y2 > 0
                    xx2 = y2*dxx2
                    
                    dxx3 = y3 > 0
                    xx3 = y3*dxx3
                    
                    dxx4 = y4 > 0
                    xx4 = y4*dxx4
                    
                    yy = bb + ww1*xx1 + ww2*xx2 + ww3*xx3 + ww4*xx4
                    yy = yy > 0
                    e = t[sp[i]] - yy
                    
                    #Updating parameters
                    ww1 = ww1 + alpha[l]*e*xx1
                    ww2 = ww2 + alpha[l]*e*xx2
                    ww3 = ww3 + alpha[l]*e*xx3
                    ww4 = ww4 + alpha[l]*e*xx4
                    
                    bb = bb + alpha[l]*e
                    
                    w11 = w11 + alpha[l]*e*ww1*dxx1*x[sp[i],0]
                    w12 = w12 + alpha[l]*e*ww1*dxx1*x[sp[i],1]
                    
                    w21 = w21 + alpha[l]*e*ww2*dxx2*x[sp[i],0]
                    w22 = w22 + alpha[l]*e*ww2*dxx2*x[sp[i],1]
                    
                    w31 = w31 + alpha[l]*e*ww3*dxx3*x[sp[i],0]
                    w32 = w32 + alpha[l]*e*ww3*dxx3*x[sp[i],1]
                    
                    w41 = w41 + alpha[l]*e*ww4*dxx4*x[sp[i],0]
                    w42 = w42 + alpha[l]*e*ww4*dxx4*x[sp[i],1]
                    
                    b1 = b1 + alpha[l]*e*ww1*dxx1
                    b2 = b2 + alpha[l]*e*ww2*dxx2
                    b3 = b3 + alpha[l]*e*ww3*dxx3
                    b4 = b4 + alpha[l]*e*ww4*dxx4
                    
                    w11f[p] = w11
                    w12f[p] = w12
                    p = p + 1
            er = 0
            for k in range(nTrain,nTrain + nTest):
                y1 = b1 + w11*x[sp[i],0] + w12*x[sp[i],1]
                y2 = b2 + w21*x[sp[i],0] + w22*x[sp[i],1]
                y3 = b3 + w31*x[sp[i],0] + w32*x[sp[i],1]
                y4 = b4 + w41*x[sp[i],0] + w42*x[sp[i],1]
                
                dxx1 = y1 > 0
                xx1 = y1*dxx1
                
                dxx2 = y2 > 0
                xx2 = y2*dxx2
                
                dxx3 = y3 > 0
                xx3 = y3*dxx3
                
                dxx4 = y4 > 0
                xx4 = y4*dxx4
                
                yy = bb + ww1*xx1 + ww2*xx2 + ww3*xx3 + ww4*xx4
                yy = yy > 0
                e = abs(t[sp[k]] - yy)
                er = er + e #Accumulates error
            
            er = er/nTest #Calculates average error
            er_List[l,j,n] = er
            
            if er_List[l,j,n] < 0.05:
                nSuccess = nSuccess + 1
        #Part C - Creating an Array that contains the success values of each
        #alpha and epoch value pair
        nSuccess_Array[l,n] = nSuccess #Array that contains the success
        
        if nEpoch < 6:
            nEpoch += 1
```

Comment: What don't you like about the way you're doing it? There's tons else I could comment generally on about your code, but the error check seems fine to me. By the way, nSuccess_Array is not previously defined in your code snippet.

Comment: Side note: you probably shouldn't be operating on scalars; that kind of defeats the purpose of NumPy

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren Thanks for the reply! I didn't post the entire code and have the nSuccess_Array defined before the first loop starts. The main issue I get is that when I went from 2 neurons to 4 neurons my success rate dropped to 0. My error ends up becoming 0 as well which makes it so my weights never update and the output of the network can't separate the two clusters. When I played around with the way I stored my error I got different results and don't know why. So I was hoping to try out a better way to store the error results and the success results to see if that improves things.

Comment: @DiehardTheTryhard Thanks for the feedback! I'm new to python and just started using it but also new to coding in general. I get that most of my variables are scalars but I used numpy mainly for the random number generation, samples, and the one tensor I used. Is there a more optimal way I should go about doing this? Any feedback on how I should go about it would be great.

Comment: @Olek Did you set the random seed to be the same when you got different results? Could just be that your initializations were different, it's typically good practice to set the random seed to something consistent (eg. 314) to separate variations from initialization, batches, etc. I'd also suggest you chunk out and dilineate your code into functions to make it more modular and readable.